# Kinetic energy of double pendulum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, oscillators

[image]

using cartesian coordinates as an intermediate step, the kinetic energy is calculated as such

[image]

why is it incorrect to just say that the kinetic energy for the first bob is $$T_1 = (1/2) m_1 (l_1\dot{\theta_1})^2$$

and for the second bob is $$T_2 = (1/2) m_2 (l_2\dot{\theta_2}+l_1 \dot{\theta_1}))^2$$

where is the $cos(\theta_1 - \theta_2)$ term coming from?

Comment: The $\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)$ is due to the articulation at point $1$, which leads to a non alignment of the two velocities. Mathematically, your two expressions are the same iff $\theta_1 = \theta_2$ ie the double pendulum is made rigid.

Comment: so what if $v_1$ (velocity of the top of second pendulum) and $v_2$(velocity of the bottom of second pendulum) do not align ? why not just add them, why do we need to consider the angle between them?

Comment: You would be adding up the magnitude of two vectors that in generall are not pointing in the same direction in space - but the relative direction matters for the length of the resultant vector

Answer (score 1):

The expression $T_2 = (1/2) m_2 (l_2\dot{\theta_2}+l_1 \dot{\theta_1}))^2$ is incorrect because you are just adding up two vector quantities algebraically.

The vector form the kinetic energy of a particle with mass $m$ is

$$ T = \tfrac{1}{2} m (\vec{v} \cdot \vec{v}) = \tfrac{1}{2} m \| \vec{v} \|^2 $$

The expression you are asking about is equal to

$$ T \overset{?}{=} \tfrac{1}{2} m_1 \| \vec{v}_1 \|^2 + \tfrac{1}{2} m_2 \| \vec{v}_2 - \vec{v}_1 \|^2 $$

which is obviously not equal to the correct expression

$$ T = \tfrac{1}{2} m_1 \| \vec{v}_1 \|^2 + \tfrac{1}{2} m_2 \| \vec{v}_2  \|^2 $$

Your first analysis is correct because it splits the velocity vector into components and considers the correct combination of $\dot{\theta}_1$ and $\dot{\theta}_2$ that yields kinetic energy.